# Text in rotated multirow cell crosses table border

Tags: tables, rotating, multirow

I'm trying to create a table like this:

[image]

For it, I wrote the following code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{one} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{one and a half~}} \\ \cline{1-2}
        two & three & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, the output is not quite as expected:

[image: screenshot]

The best workaround for this I found so far was this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74550/22718. But it seems a bit excessive, especially considering I need this layout in multiple places and for every column I would have to write something like `\setbox0\hbox{\tabular{@{}l}Metszéspontok\\ Száma\endtabular}`, if I understand correctly. Also, to my mind, it's pretty simple formatting, I achieved this in LO Calc with a few mouse clicks, so it should be not that difficult in LaTeX, right?

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{one} 
        & \\ \cline{1-2}
        two & three & 
  \rotatebox{90}{one and a half~\hspace{-\normalbaselineskip}}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```